# PHP (Codeigniter 3) Session is getting destroyed after redirect in Google Cloud Platform, but working properly in Localhost and Cpanel

Tags: php, codeigniter, google-cloud-platform, codeigniter-3, cpanel

I have developed project in codeigniter, and it is working properly in cpanel server as well as on xammp on localhost, one of my client required same project but he needs project to be hosted on cloud platform, i have configured all things on GCP, but when i tried to login i realised that sessions are getting destroyed after login.

```
$this->set_session($user);
print_r($_SESSION);
//redirect('processor');
```

this show proper result
but after redirected to processor controller it just return me value of session named  $_SESSION['__ci_last_regenerate']

Comment: This is cookie related issue. Close browser or restart PC. Or Use Session Database to store session.

Comment: Have you got any errors?

Comment: How did you configure your project? Where on Google Cloud Platform do you run your application: App Engine, Compute Engine, Kubernetes Engine? How do you store session: Filesystem, Memory, Database? Note that in the default Codeigniter setup, session is stored on filesystem. This would work on a local system, or on a single server, but fail in a distributed environment. If you are on App Engine this post on Hosting CodeIgniter on Google App Engine should help you to get started: http://www.hthirukkumaran.com/cloud-development/hosting-codeigniter-on-google-app-engine/

Comment: `set_session` is not a CI method... is that an internal function you built? It's always tricky to use CI's session library mixed with native PHP session handling (yes, CI's session library is a wrapper for the latter, but they tend to not like each other when mixed). Also, like @Ryan stated above, if you're on a distributed environment and using a local filesystem for session handling, you will face this issues. You should move your session handling to another driver (database would be the simplest for your need)